# My script has the answe :TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. How I solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, python-import, pyserial

I am trying to use serial port but I have no sucess with the simple program below. Somebody can help me? I run the script the result is:

**TypeError: 'module' object is not callable**

I change de serial to Serial and I put the b => ser.write(b,'A)

I dont know a answer to solve it

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=0,
    stopbits=1,
    bytesize=8,
    timeout=1
)

while 1:
    ser.write(b'A')
    x=ser.readline()
    print (x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you've installed `pyserial` and not `serial` through pip.

Then, from the docs [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports), the command is actually `serial.Serial`, so the following should work:

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=0,
    stopbits=1,
    bytesize=8,
    timeout=1
)
```

Also, note that `ser.write()` takes a bytes object, so you should change this to

```
ser.write(b'A')
```

Edit: given the stack trace in the comments, the issue was that the asker's python file was called serial.py, causing it to try to import itself rather than the serial module. Renaming their py file would solve this.

Comment: Yes, I installed pyserial and I changed the write command, but no sucess

Comment: Which line throws the error? Are you using `serial.Serial` with a capital `S`?

Comment: That sounds like you have the wrong module installed. What is the output if you do `serial.__version__`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/serial.py", line 1, in <module>
    import serial
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 276, in _custom_import
    module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/serial.py", line 3, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'